# What is > operator doing in the shell (argpare python module)?

Tags: python, shell, argparse

This is what I execute in the terminal: `python test.py display -n 10 -f output.out --start_date 2020-01-01 --end_date 2020-01-10 --filter distance:>=:5`

While executing the code, until using `--filter distance:=>:5` the program parse arguments correctly when it reaches `distance:>=:5` filter equals to "distance:" and it prints everything in the file named "=:5".

test.py (removed help and others for readablity):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("action",
                    choices=["display", "csvfil"])
parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int, required=True)
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--start_date")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--end_date")
parser.add_argument("-filt", "--filter")
a = parser.parse_args()
print(a)
```

The file called **=:5**

```
Namespace(action='display', end_date='2020-01-10', file='output.out', filter='distance:', number=10, start_date='2020-01-01')
```

Comment: The shell is interpreting the '>' as `stdout` redirection.  It does not get passed to `sys.argv` (you can check that) or to the `parser`.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this, except using quotes?

Comment: Does there need to be another way?

Comment: Not really, just curious if I can "bypass" the redirection.

Comment: You can use a backslash (`\`) to escape a single character, if you dislike quotes.